# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n$ zero or undefined?

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n$$
Is this mathematical expression zero or undefined?
I think it looks like zero but i can't explain the reason mathematically.
In addition, $\infty - \infty$ is undefined afaik?

Comment: The series is _irregular_ (neither converges nor diverges) and you could say the sum is undefined.

Comment: I assume that was a typo.

Comment: In addition to the (correct!) answers that this limit is undefined, your intuition that it "looks like zero" is not completely wrong. You may find the following article interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_limit

Comment: despite this sum isn't finite in a conentional sense, it is $1/2$ in any well defined regularisation scheme. For example using Abel or Cesaro summation...

Comment: @tired You probably mean $-1/2$.

Comment: @Did sure, thanks for spotting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, if $\sum a_n$ converges, it must be the case that $a_n \to 0$. In the case of this series, $(-1)^n=-1,0,-1,0$ doesn't converge to *anything*,so it certainly does not tend to $0$, and so you can deduce that the series is divergent.

For your last comment, referring to $\infty-\infty$ suggests to me that you are doing the following: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{2n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{2n+1} ``=" \infty-\infty.$$

However, you  can only re-order infinitely many terms in a series (assuming you want a sensible result) if the series is absolutely convergent, which $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$ is not, since $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |-1^n|=\sum_{n=1}^{n} 1^n=1+1+1+...$$

Answer (score 2):

It is undefined. The sequence of partial sums is $-1, 0, -1, 0...$ which, while bounded, does not converge.